# Apple Verify the JWS E256 signature using the server’s public key

Tags: java, ios, jwt, sign-in-with-apple

New to Apple environment.
Following this guide lines https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple_rest_api/verifying_a_user

Trying to do "`Verify the JWS E256 signature using the server’s public key`" of an **Apple Identity Token(JWT)** which was received at iOS app during `"Sign In With Apple"` and was sent to Java App Server.

According to this https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/125731

My codes are as follows -

```
import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.spec.KeySpec;
import java.security.spec.RSAPublicKeySpec;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.List;


public class AppleTest {


    @Test
    public void test(String appleToken) throws Exception {


        AppleKeySet appleKeySet = new RestTemplateBuilder().build()
                .getForObject("https://appleid.apple.com/auth/keys", AppleKeySet.class);

        List<Key> applePublicKeys = appleKeySet.getKeys();
        Key key = applePublicKeys.get(0);

        BigInteger n = new BigInteger(1, Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(key.getN()));
        BigInteger e = new BigInteger(1, Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(key.getE()));

        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        KeySpec publicKeySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(n, e);
        PublicKey publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);

        Claims claims = Jwts.parser()
                .setSigningKey(publicKey)
                .parseClaimsJws(appleToken)
                .getBody();
    }
}
```

Key POJO:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Key {

    @JsonProperty("kty")
    private String kty;
    @JsonProperty("kid")
    private String kid;
    @JsonProperty("use")
    private String use;
    @JsonProperty("alg")
    private String alg;
    @JsonProperty("n")
    private String n;
    @JsonProperty("e")
    private String e;
}
```

But, I am getting `JWT signature does not match locally computed signature.`

I am using implementation `io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.9.1` for JWT.
What could be wrong?

Comment: `applePublicKeys.get(0);` looks suspicious. You can't just pick any key. You need to pick the matching key.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Can you please mention - How to pick the right key?

Comment: *kid* is identifier that needs to match. It's found both in the JWT header and in Apple's list of keys.

Comment: Possibly you can simplify your code with Jose4J like so: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60722164/413337

Comment: @Codo Thank you so much. That kid was the missing part on my code. I got it working now. Thank you so much!!! 